# Why does maven not run Junit tests after 'clean'

Tags: java, maven, junit, dropwizard

I am building a Java RESTful web service using dropwizard. The tests do not run consistently though. If I run the test manually, then `mvn test` the test will run.

If I run `mvn clean test` I get

> No tests to run.

Until I run the test manually again. My project structure is as follows:

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <groupId>com.workflowstreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflowstreamer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WorkflowStreamer</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>1.3.7</dropwizard.version>
        <mainClass>com.workflowstreamer.WorkflowStreamerApplication</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.7</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "run the test manually"?

Comment: Check your `target/test-classes` directory. It sounds like the test classes aren't getting compiled. You also haven't specified where they're located.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. It problem was with my test folder structure.

```
[] src
  [] main
    [] ...
  [] test
    [] java
      [] ...
```

java was not set as the "Test Sources Root". So the test-classes were not generated.

I was able to find a solution after @chrylis pointed me in the right direction in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980969/why-does-maven-not-run-junit-tests-after-clean#comment92868535_52980969).